# two non-diffeomorphic manifolds with the same cohomoly classes.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Question: Calculate the de Rham cohomology groups of:  $U=\mathbb{R}^3 - (L \cup C)$ and $V= \mathbb{R}^3 - (L' \cup C)$, where $L' = \{x = 2, y = 0\}$, $L = \{x = y = 0\}$ and $C=\{ x^2 + y^2 = 1, z=0\}$. Then conclude that they are not diffeomorphic.

I did the calculation of the Cohomology groups and they are the same. But I'm not seeing why $U$ and $V$ are not diffeomorphic.

I found $H^0(U) = \mathbb{R}$, $H^1(U) = \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, $H^2(U) = \mathbb{R}$ and $H^r(U) = 0$ for all $r\geq 3$.

Comment: I'm guessing the fundamental groups are different.

Comment: I didn't use this to find the cohomoly groups but I think that $U$ has the same homotopy type of the torus, so the fundamental group would be easy, but in the case of $V$ how can I do the calculation?

Comment: I would've known how to do it years ago but I've forgotten.

Comment: There aren't that many tools for computing fundamental groups - what tools do you have available?

Comment: You can use whatever works =)

Comment: Have you computed what the wedge map (i.e. the cup product) does to cohomology? In other words in each of your examples for essential closed one forms $\alpha$ and $\beta$ what is $[\alpha \wedge \beta]$?